# CF Garden-runC as a container orchestration engine?

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, runc, diego, garden-runc

I have been looking at Garden-runC / Guardian and am wondering if it can be used outside of CloudFoundry as a container orchestration engine.

From what I have been able to understand so far:

A garden client can use the Garden API to talk to a backend implementation (in this case Gaurdian), which would be able to deploy a container using its runtime (runC).

It would also perhaps require a wshd process to be packaged as part of the container, as that is what garden seems to use to control execution of processes inside the container.

While I realise that it's a lot more complex than that, and I am not sure how the backend would get the image it needs, etc., would it at least in theory be possible to use Garden / Guardian as a container orchestration engine?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden-runc-release

Try deploying it to boshlite. See if it works. You can then build your manifest to the same.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). Clarifying questions belong in comments to the question. (And discussions can be conducted in chat.)

Comment: Thanks Peter!

Just out of curiosity, why do you want to use Garden-runc outside of CF? Docker is good at that. You can use Kubernetes to manage. You have all sorts of documentation available for this paradigm.

So, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?